# Save & Publish disabled for two dimensional array Customizer

Tags: customization, settings-api, theme-customizer

I am developing custom control in customizer.

## Control

Its 4-5 textboxes that I can sort internally. Its a foreach loop.
textbox1
textbox2
textbox3 ..

The data stored is in array. $theme['textbox'][$key] where key is 1.2,3,4 etc.

Here when I edit text boxes, the save button is still disabled.
Also when I use $this->link() its not working.
I tried to directly add 'data-customize-setting-link' = 'theme[textbox][1]', but its not working.

Please help how to handle two dimensional array in customizer and how to save data for such custom control.
Is there any hook to trigger save etc.

Thanks